# submitting aspx form with Php I have the view but not the data

Tags: php, asp.net, forms, curl

I want to have the coupon data from planet win I have the view, but not the coupon data. I use all the params of asp forms but I can't have the coupon data please help. I think that I have a problem in the form data or the site work with web service the request header of the xhr rquest is

> POST /Sport/default.aspx HTTP/1.1 Host: ww3.365planetwinall.net
>   Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 10353 Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Origin: https://ww3.365planetwinall.net X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 Accept: */* Referer:
>   https://ww3.365planetwinall.net/Sport/default.aspx Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language:
>   fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ar;q=0.2 Cookie:
>   Comm100_CC_Identity_178373=-28931327; ISBets_CurrentOddsFormat=1;
>   ISBets_CurrentGMT=41; ASP.NET_SessionId=i2avbkrxv4pvls55sw4d1j45;
>   __utmt=1; __utma=1.1764843245.1455596018.1473978904.1474078088.172; __utmb=1.2.10.1474078088; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1473331905.170.21.utmcsr=zalozi.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/planetwin365;
>   comm100_session_178373=-35985514;
>   comm100_guid2_178373=5d22b4d2847a4e0d82cc3db3afeb5177;
>   ISBets_CurrentCulture=11; _ga=GA1.2.1764843245.1455596018;
>   _dc_gtm_UA-63917352-3=1; _ga=GA1.3.1764843245.1455596018; _dc_gtm_UA-63917352-10=1

```
 <?php

$url = "https://ww3.365planetwinall.net/Sport/default.aspx";
$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US)  

AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';

//$username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
//$password = "XXXXXXXXXX";


$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); // file to write request header for debug  

  purpose

/**
    Get __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION
 */
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];



/**
 Start Login process
 */
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();

$postfields['h$w$SM'] = 'h$w$PC$cCoupon$atlasCoupon|h$w$PC$cCoupon$lnkCaricaCouponCodiceAnonimo';
$postfields['h$w$cLogin$ctrlLogin$Username'] = "";
$postfields['h$w$cLogin$ctrlLogin$Password'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$oddsSearch$txtSearch'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cSport$hidSportTime'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$ctl02$txtVincita'] = "100";
$postfields['h$w$PC$ctl02$txtGiocata'] = "1";
$postfields['h$w$PC$CouponCheck1$txtCodiceCoupon'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$ctl12$hidQuoteCoupon'] =              

 '4177834906§4189204249§4192948716§4191682218§4192727992§';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidRiserva'] = "0";
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidAttesa'] = "0";
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidCouponAsincrono'] = "0";
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidIsTemporaryCoupon'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidTipoCoupon'] = "4";
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidStatoCoupon'] = "0";
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidBonusNumScommesse'] = "1.1000";
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidQuotaTotaleDIMax'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidQuotaTotaleDIMin'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidQuotaTotale'] = '112,66';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidIDQuote'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidModificatoQuote'] = "1";
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidBonusQuotaMinimaAttivo'] = "0";
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidBonusRaggruppamentoMinimo'] = '0';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidNumItemCoupon'] = '0';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidPrintAsincronoDisabled'] = '0';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtCouponCodiceAnonimo'] = 'TD426';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDQuota'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtSottoEventName'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtQuota'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtCodPubblicazione'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDEvento'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtEventName'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDSottoEvento'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtGiocabilita'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtTipoQuota'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDTipoEvento'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDTipoQuota'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtQB'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtAddImporto'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDCouponPrecompilato'] = '';
$postfields['h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtImportoCouponPrecompilato'] = '';
$postfields['__EVENTTARGET'] = "h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnFakeLoad";
$postfields['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = "";
$postfields['__ASYNCPOST'] = "true";
$postfields['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = "15C4A0A3";
$postfields['__VIEWSTATE'] = $viewstate;
$postfields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $eventValidation;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); // Get result after login page.

var_dump($ret) ;
echo 'Erreur Curl : ' . curl_error($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it wouldn't surprise me if your problem is simply,
you send the POST request using `multipart/form-data`,
a lot of servers don't parse that correctly, and 
would expect `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead.
to fix that, replace `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);` with
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));`

other notes:

do not
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`
simply do
`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);`
instead.

your UA string contains newlines. pretty sure that's not what you want, i don't know any browser that actually has a newline in the user-agent header.

for the sake of portability, fopen with 'wb'

it would probably be better to use DOMDocument to parse your html.

`$viewstate=(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html))->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->getAttribute("value");
$eventValidation=(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html))->getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION')->getAttribute("value");`

(a lot of experts agree on that regular expressions are not fit for parsing html. see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for example)

setting CURLOPT_ENCODING to empty string would magically make your transfers faster.

if you don't need the cookies after the script has finished, you should probably do

`$ckfileh=tmpfile();
$ckfile=stream_get_meta_data($ckfileh)['uri'];` instead of tmpnam() as it will automatically clear the tmpfiles() at the end of script execution, wheras your tmpnam() approach leaves junk in /tmp unless you manually explicitly delete it on script completion.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_headers_from_curl_response($headerContent) {

    $headers = [];

    // Split the string on every "double" new line.
    $arrRequests = explode("\r\n\r\n", $headerContent);

    // Loop of response headers. The "count() -1" is to
    //avoid an empty row for the extra line break before the body of the esponse.
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($arrRequests) - 1; $index++) {

        foreach (explode("\r\n", $arrRequests[$index]) as $i => $line) {
            if ($i === 0) {
                $headers[$index]['http_code'] = $line;
            }
            else {
                list ($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);
                $headers[$index][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $headers;
}

function regexExtract($text, $regex, $regs, $nthValue) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $text, $regs)) {
        $result = $regs[$nthValue];
    }
    else {
        $result = "";
    }

    return $result;
}

$regexViewstate = '/__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';
$regexEventVal   = '/__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';

$ch = curl_init("https://m3.365planetwinall.net/Schedina.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$viewstate = regexExtract($response, $regexViewstate, $regs, 1);
$eventval  = regexExtract($response, $regexEventVal, $regs, 1);

$params = [
'__EVENTTARGET'=>'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$lnkCaricaCouponCodiceAnonimo',
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=>'748FF232',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT'     => '',
    '__VIEWSTATE'         => $viewstate,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION'   => $eventval,
    'ctl00$w$SM'=>'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$atlasCoupon|ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$lnkCaricaCouponCodiceAnonimo',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidRiserva'=>'0',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidAttesa'=>'0',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidTipoCoupon'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidStatoCoupon'=>'0',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidBonusNumScommesse'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidQuotaTotaleDIMax'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidQuotaTotaleDIMin'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidQuotaTotale'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidIDQuote'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidModificatoQuote'=>'1',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidBonusQuotaMinimaAttivo'=>'0',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidBonusRaggruppamentoMinimo'=>'0',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidNumItemCoupon'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidIDCoupon'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$hidPrintAsincronoDisabled'=>'0',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$txtCouponCodiceAnonimo'=>$code_coupon,
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$txtIDQuota'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$txtQB'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$txtAddImporto'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$txtIDCouponPrecompilato'=>'',
'ctl00$w$ContentMain$ContentMain$Coupon1$txtImportoCouponPrecompilato'=>'',
'__ASYNCPOST'=>'false'
    ];

$ch2 = curl_init("https://m3.365planetwinall.net/Schedina.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies2.txt');

$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

foreach (get_headers_from_curl_response($response2) as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $value2) {
       // echo $key.": ".$value2."<br />";
    }
}
```